# Prometheus alertmanager not sending mail after the alert fire

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I've installed prometheus using HELM and I configured an alert to fire when I have more than x pod the alert work as expected but I want to send mail whenever the alert fire so I added this config in the values.yml file but I dont receive any mails

```
alertmanager:
  enabled: true
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    receivers:
      - name: email-notifier
        email_configs:
          - to: "mymail@gmail.com"
            from: mnalouti@gmail.com
            smarthost: smtp.gmail.com:587
            auth_username: "mymail@gmail.com"
            auth_password: 'pas"pas"pas"pas'
            require_tls: true
```

What am doing wrong ?